# How to recover plaintext from .MX files?

Tags: import, files-and-directories, binary, format, dumpsave

I need a function to deserialize the contents of an MX source file for reading. We can’t simply use `Get` because I don’t want to load or run the code, but rather to read whatever in the file? Is there such a function in existence, if not how could we write this `UnscrambleSourceMXFile[]`, if this is even possible?

Comment: I mean, in general no. That’s part of why one would put the source in an MX file. And if it’s `Locked` and `ReadProtected` there’s absolutely no way. On the other hand, if you know what symbols are declared in the MX file you can use ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitionsLocal`` to see the definitions of those.

Comment: I am not sure about this, but I always suspected that this is not possible with MX files as they directly encode in-memory definitions. In fact, MX files cannot even contain a plain expression. All they can contain is assigned definitions. When you `Export` a plain expression to MX, it will first be assigned to special internal symbol, then this symbol is `DumpSave`d. `Import` will `Get` the file, then check the definition of that symbol.

Comment: This is very different from other serializations such as an `.m` file, `Compress` or sending through MathLink. All those encode a plain expression. If that expression is evaluated, that can in turn create definitions. I *think* MX is the opposite: it just saves the kernel state associated with some symbols.