# Unable to use a function from Get with Encode

Tags: import, packages, contexts

I am trying to create a proprietary function as discussed in this link:

> [How to distribute proprietary Mathematica code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1571/how-to-distribute-proprietary-mathematica-code)

So I create a function and dump it into a file

```
f[x_Real] := x^2 + 1;
SetAttributes[f, {ReadProtected, Locked}]

SetDirectory[$TemporaryDirectory];
DumpSave["notEncodedFunction.mx", f]
```

After I quit and load the file it works

```
Quit[]

SetDirectory[$TemporaryDirectory];
Get["notEncodedFunction.mx"]
f[5.1]
```

> 27.01

I now try to repeat the above but with an encoded version and it fails

```
Quit[]

SetDirectory[$TemporaryDirectory];
Encode["notEncodedFunction.mx", "encodedFunction.mx"];

Get["encodedFunction.mx"];
f[5.1]
```

> f[5.1]

I feel I am overlooking something obvious here but what?

PS: If copying the code to the notebook please split put the `Quit[]` line in its own cell

Comment: The only examples I see for `Encode` use plain text files, not binary formats like MX.  I can't say whether what you are seeing is a bug or not. But I am curious what the intent is for encoding an MX file - the file format is [not readable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/211339/9490) except by the kernel.

Comment: Following the answer in the link: "...to use a combination of encryption, `DumpSave`..." I took "encryption" to refer to `Encode`